# I am getting an error - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'"

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

I am using a custom cell in my tableView but when I run i get the error which I have mentioned in my question.

```
 self.districtTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PlaceCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "placeCell")

 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // TODO: Your app can do something when textField finishes editing

    print("The textField ended editing. Do something based on app requirements.")
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return districts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "placeCell") as! PlaceTableViewCell
    // Set text from the data model
    cell.distLabel.text = districts[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = distTextField.font
    return cell
```

How can I get rid of this error. I have used different methods for registering a cell in table view. But it does not works. please help

Comment: Your nib class needs to extend from UITableViewCell

Comment: Are you sure you added UITableViewCell to the xib file? and xib file containing only that one?

Comment: @Purushothaman Yes.

Comment: @RakeshMohan : Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442311/invalid-nib-registered-for-identifier-cellname-nib-must-contain-exactly-one

Comment: @RakeshMohan Are you having multiple view inside xib file?

Comment: For me this error was showing because, i had an extra empty Cell inside xib file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using xib of tableviewcell then register your xib like this in viewDidLoad.

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "PlaceTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "placeCell")
```

If you are using custom class of tableViewcell then try this one,

```
let placeCell : PlaceTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "placeCell") as! PlaceTableViewCell
```

As I am seeing your code work is almost correct. Hope my answer helps you.

Answer (score 74):

### I have added **Tap gestures** from Interface builder (XIB).

Remove that will solve this issue.

You have to add **gesture** in xib by **programatically** way

Comment: But why it's like that??

Comment: i had the same problem thanks! i thought this worked before in previous xcode/ios versions but i am not sure

Answer (score 45):

In my case it was a view which was added outside the cell. It shouldn't have been there

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Having multiple table view cells in a .xib file also causes this error.
Moving the table view cells in to their own separate .xib files resolved my error.

> nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance

Answer (score 13):

Open your 'PlaceCollectionViewCell.xib' file. Make sure there's only one top level view (look at the side panel, not just the canvas, it may not be visible). Make sure your view has a class assigned that is subclass of UITableViewCell (not UICollectionViewCell, xib name looks suspicious to me), as well as Reuse Identifier.

[image: only one view on top level]

[image: has class and reuse identifier]

Comment: I somehow dragged some view to my cell and got the crash. Thanks a lot, saved me some time.

Answer (score 6):

The error can be misleading. I somehow dragged some view to my cell and it created another level of view out of the main view. just remove that from your xib nd error must go

Comment: Happened to me too. An extra label somehow created by me out of the cell in the Xib file can cause this confusing error message.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was I hadn't all the necessary constraints in my cell. Check it out

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your "Identifier" property in the "Attribute inspector" panel is set to the specified Reuse Identifier from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a very the same issue in MacOS while using `NSCollectionView`, and finally figured out I have to drag and drop one `NSCollectionViewItem` to the collection view's item xib file.
[image]